# How should I reword this virtualization question?

Tags: discussion

The latest question of mine "[when not to use virtualisation](https://serverfault.com/questions/451651/when-not-to-use-virtualisation)" got closed pretty fast.

The assumption for the close was that it would cause debate/discussion (my guess, after I reviewed the comment about KVM/VMWare) - I would rather have expected "not a real question", since the question is somewhat broad.

Anyway I think the question is still interesting, but I have no really good idea on how to reword it, so that answers will stay on focus without causing discussion.

I welcome any ideas about it - even if the idea is "this is the wrong place to ask that".

Comment: General commentary: If you fee your question needs something like `Update I do not want a debate on this topic - just your facts. Optimal responses would come from people using a broad range of servers and a broad range of techniques.` added to it, that's usually a sign it's not a good question. *Good questions should not require inline explanation of what you (the asker) wants*: Good Answers should proceed naturally from the question. If they don't there's usually a fundamental flaw in the question...

Comment: @voretaq7 I had an uneasy feeling about this question right when I asked it - it is in a very grey area - I knew that, but the question and answers should help professional sysadmins - and that is right on focus, is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I dunno, if we can allow these questions:

- [Good reasons to keep 32-bit Microsoft Windows desktop OSes](https://serverfault.com/questions/429299/good-reasons-to-keep-32-bit-microsoft-windows-desktop-oses)
- [To virtualize, or not to virtualize](https://serverfault.com/questions/69384/to-virtualize-or-not-to-virtualize) (historical, the site has evolved since then)

(ok so that's all I could find on a whim, but I know there are others in the same vein) then I'm willing to give your question a 2nd chance. I'll let others give their feedback on meta first and keep an eye on it before re-opening it though.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and re-open. The answers up until now go into the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

What are you trying to ask?

"When should I not virtualize" is an enormously open-ended question with a huge breadth of possible answers. There's no possible way for an answer (or set of answers) to encompass all of them - it would degrade quickly into a forum-style "But that works for me" / "that doesn't work in environments where `X`" free-for-all.

As was pointed out in the comments, this is also not something that can be answered generically - the hypervisor(s) you're using and possibly even the guest OS will play important roles in the answer.

---

Bottom line for me, this question as written runs afoul of this chunk of our [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

The only way I can see to salvage it would be to reword the question as a specific application of virtualization technology (hypervisor, underlying server/storage/network subsystems) and intended workload.
Even that would be bordering on "too localized" -- it's a performance question that can really only be answered by benchmarking and deciding if your system's performance as a VM would be adequate. Every environment will generate its own rules on what can/can't virtualize based on in-house knowledge of the workloads and capability of the virtualization platform.

Comment: I've just done exactly as you suggested; re-worded it asking for specific metrics/answers rather than "What do you think?"

Comment: @MarkHenderson: It's still asking for a list(s) of <Things> which doesn't produce good authoritative answers.

Comment: @Iain - it's asking for a list of metrics, which is generally on-topic, as per the let's go shopping link we love to link. Don't ask "What's best?" ask "What makes something the best". I feel this is another variation of that.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yeah I'm generally OK with it as a "What should I measure to see if virtualization is going to suck for me?" question

Comment: There were two reasons to ask this question. First - I came across that our Windows-Hyper-V-guys developed quite the same limits as we did with Linux/XEN. Second there was a question on how to reduce interrupts in a VM where the network-interrupts maxed out on a specific interface. IMHO this would max out on any VM-technique (if you stay with the same hardware).

Answer (score 0):

It's a crap and highly subjective question and I've voted to close it again. There are at least two good close reasons:

1. Not constructive
2. Not a real question

Take your pick.

That fact that there are still some old equally crappy and subjective questions on the site is no reason to accept any more.